# Appending compiler flags to a file with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

How do I add a compiler flag (I want to APPEND it, not overwrite the others) to a single translation unit with cmake?

I tried with

```
set_source_files_properties(MyFile.cpp PROPERTIES CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-msse4.1")
```

but it isn't working.. any advice on how to do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For CMake 3.0 or later, use the [COMPILE_OPTIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html) property to add a flag to a single translation unit, i.e.:

```
set_property(SOURCE MyFile.cpp APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS "-msse4.1")
```

For earlier versions of CMake, use the [COMPILE_FLAGS](https://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#prop_sf:COMPILE_FLAGS) property. `COMPILE_FLAGS` is a string property. Therefore the correct way to append additional options to it is to use the `APPEND_STRING` variant of the [set_property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html) command:

```
set_property(SOURCE MyFile.cpp APPEND_STRING PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS " -msse4.1 ")
```

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there, this should work:

```
set_property(SOURCE MyFile.cpp APPEND PROPERTY CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -msse4.1)
```

The kind-specific helpers (like `set_source_files_properties()`) can be handy at times, but they have a very simiplified interface. For non-trivial things, you have to use `set_property()`. I've found that I actually rarely use the helpers at all.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
set_property(SOURCE MyFile.cpp APPEND PROPERTY CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-msse4.1")
```

By the way, a few properties are *always appended*, for example, COMPILE_FLAGS.  For those you don't need to do anything special, just set them and they get appended :)