# CMake: Is there a difference between set_property(TARGET ...) and set_target_properties?

Tags: cmake

In CMake, assuming one is just setting one property, is there any difference between

```
set_target_properties(target PROPERTIES prop value)
```

and

```
set_property(TARGET target PROPERTY prop value)
```

?

Cf documentation at:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html

which imply there is no difference but aren't that clear.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Consider `set_target_properties()` as a specialized form of `set_property()`.

#### Advantages of ...

- `set_target_properties(...)` is a convenience function because it allows to set multiple properties of multiple targets.

  For example:

  ```perl
  add_executable(a ...)
  add_executable(b ...)
  set_target_properties(
      a 
      b
      PROPERTIES 
          LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX
          FOLDER          "Executable"
  )
  ```
- `set_property(TARGET ...)` can `APPEND` to a list- or `APPEND_STRING` to a string-based property of targets.

  For example:

  ```perl
  add_executable(a ...)
  set_property(
      TARGET a
      APPEND PROPERTY
          INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
  )
  ```

#### References

- [How to change the name of the output binary to not be a.out with CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904273/how-to-change-the-name-of-the-output-binary-to-not-be-a-out-with-cmake)
- [target_include_directories prior to 2.8.12?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900332/target-include-directories-prior-to-2-8-12)
- [Appending compiler flags to a file with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244800/appending-compiler-flags-to-a-file-with-cmake)

Comment: `set_property` supports multiple targets too: `set_property(TARGET a b c ...)`

Comment: @NikitaNemkin Any practical example is welcome.

Answer (score 10):

The difference is that with `set_property`, you get to define the scope. You actually have more options with the `set_property` other than just specifying a target, such as specifying source files in a list to have a certain property.

For example:

```
set_property(SOURCE src1.cpp src2.cpp PROPERTY SKIP_AUTOMOC ...)
```

This will add the SKIP_AUTOMOC property to source files listed. (This is for Qt, where Moc'ing of objects occurs automatically and sometimes you don't want that).

Contrast with `set_target_properties` where you must specify a Target and the property and it's value.

```
set_target_properties(target PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 11 ...)
```

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 9):

Note that you also have respective `set_*_properties` functions for some of the other types of properties: [`set_source_files_properties`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/set_source_files_properties.html), [`set_directory_properties`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/set_directory_properties.html) and [`set_tests_properties`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/set_tests_properties.html). Notably absent are setters for install and global properties.

The reason for that is that these functions predate the general [`set_property`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/set_property.html) call, which was only introduced with CMake 2.6, together with a general overhaul of the property system to what it is today.

These days, people tend to prefer the generic `set_property`, as it is the more modern function and provides a few additional features. It also offers a more consistent syntax than the old functions (eg. `set_directory_properties` not allowing to specify the directory as a parameter, set_source_file**s** vs set_director**y**, etc.).

There is not a strong technical reason for preferring `set_property`, but I would consider it slightly better style than using the old, specific functions.