# target_compile_definitions for multiple CMake targets?

Tags: cmake, dry, idioms, compiler-options

I've [been](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsXLMQ6WgIk) [told](https://www.slideshare.net/DanielPfeifer1/cmake-48475415) it's bad practice to do things like seting `CFLAGS` directly in CMake, and that, instead, I should use the `target_compile_definitions()` command.

Ok, but - what if I want to use similar/identical definitions for multiple (independent) targets? I don't want to repeat myself over and over again.

Comment: The link is not working (at least now). `bad practice to do things like seting CFLAGS directly in CMake` - If you talk about setting variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, then it depends from what kind of options you want to set. No needs to completely avoid setting the variable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Added a video link.

Comment: @einpoklum for our internal build system, used by everyone in our company for all our builds, we set `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` directly, so they are the same for all targets. In our case it makes sense. If you want to open source your project, and have others consume your CMakeLists via ExternalProject, then doing so would be considered bad practice, as you're foisting your build flags on your users. It depends on your situation

Comment: @SteveLorimer - `... have others consume your CMakeLists via ExternalProject, then doing so would be considered bad practice` - ExternalProject doesn't affect on project's `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. Do you mean `add_subdirectory` instead?

Comment: @SteveLorimer: Actually, on second though, note that it doesn't matter whether others consume your your CMakeLists via ExternalProject or whether it's just users building it - it's still bad practice since if a user has a different C/C++ compiler with a different flag syntax then you could be screwed either way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see three possible ways:

1. The preferred one using [`target_compile_definitions(... INTERFACE/PUBLIC ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html) which would self-propagate the compiler definitions to targets depending on it via [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) command.
2. Using the [`set_property(TARGET target1 target2 ... APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html) to set the same definitions to multiple targets.
3. You may still use the "old commands" of [`add_definitions()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html) and [`remove_definitions()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/remove_definitions.html) to modify [`COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html) directory property (which would pre-set all [`COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html) target properties in this directories scope).

#### References

- [Is Cmake set variable recursive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828855/is-cmake-set-variable-recursive)
- [CMake: Is there a difference between set_property(TARGET ...) and set_target_properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47416090/cmake-is-there-a-difference-between-set-propertytarget-and-set-target-pro)

Comment: Edited my question to rule out option 1 - that's not the situation I meant. I'll try option 2... and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Note that option 2. is probably only a good idea if all the targets are being created in the same directory as the `set_property` call. Modern CMake  relies on you keeping settings localized and close to the definition of the targets. I personally would consider 'long-distance' manipulation of target properties bad style.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr: You can iterate the targets in a loop.**

If you have a bunch of targets with some common/similar features, you may want to simply manipulate them all in a loop! Remember - CMake is not like GNU Make, it's a full-fledged scripting language (well, sort of). So you could write:

```
set(my_targets
    foo
    bar
    baz)

foreach(TARGET ${my_targets})
    add_executable(${TARGET} "${TARGET}.cu")
    target_compile_options(${TARGET} PRIVATE "--some_option=some_value")
    target_link_libraries(${TARGET} PRIVATE some_lib)
    # and so on
    set_target_properties(
        ${TARGET}
        PROPERTIES
        C_STANDARD 99
        C_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES
        C_EXTENSIONS NO )
endforeach(TARGET)
```

And you could also initialize an empty list of targets, then add to it here-and-there, and only finally apply your common options and settings to all of them, centrally.

Note: In this example I added `PRIVATE` compile options, but if you need some of them to propagate to targets *using* your targets, you can make them `PUBLIC`).

Answer (score 1):

another neat solution is to define an interface library target (a fake target that does not produce any binaries) with all required properties and compiler definitions, then link the other existing targets against it

example:

```
add_library(myfakelib INTERFACE)
target_compile_definitions(myfakelib INTERFACE MY_NEEDED_DEFINITION)

add_executable(actualtarget1 main1.cpp)
add_executable(actualtarget2 main2.cpp)

set_property(
    TARGET actualtarget1 actualtarget2
    APPEND PROPERTY LINK_LIBRARIES myfakelib
)
```

refs:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries

Comment: Does it have to be an interface library target? Can't it be some kind of generic artificial target? Also, will a library target propagate the C-language properties?

Comment: any library target will propagate properties, "INTERFACE" type is actually an "artificial" type that does not produce any binaries, just as I've mentioned